# Classifying projective representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, mathematics, lie-algebra

Blagoje Oblak in their thesis "[BMS particles in three dimensions](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-61878-4)” says that

> "Given a group $G,$ suppose we wish to find all its projective unitary representations. The above considerations [in the thesis] provide an algorithm that allows us, in principle, to solve the problem:
>
> 1. First find the universal cover $\tilde{G}$ of $G$ to take care of topological central extensions.
> 2. Then find the most general central extension $\hat{\tilde{G}}$ of $\tilde{G}$ in order to take care of differentiable central extensions.
> 3. Finally, consider an exact unitary representation of $\hat{\tilde{G}}$; any projective unitary representation of $G$ may be seen as a representation of that type.

**What I know**:

(a) If $T:G\to U(PH)$ is a unitary projective representation (i.e. a map $T:G\to U(H)$ with $T(f)T(g)=e^{iC(f,g)}T(fg)$ for all $f,g\in G$), then $C:G\times G\to \mathbb{R}$ is a real 2-cocycle on $G$, i.e. $[C]\in H^2 (G;\mathbb{R})$.

(b) $H^2 (G;\mathbb{R})$ classifies central extensions of $G$, i.e. for every $[C]\in H^2 (G;\mathbb{R})$, $\hat{G}_C \equiv G\times \mathbb{R}$ with group action $(f,\lambda)\cdot (g,\mu ):=(fg,\lambda +\mu +C(f,g))$ is a central extension of $G$ by $\mathbb{R}$, if $\hat{G}$ is a central extension of $G$ by $\mathbb{R}$, then there exists $[C]\in H^2 (G;\mathbb{R})$ such that $\hat{G}=\hat{G}_C$, and $[C]=[C']$ iff $\hat{G}_C$ and $\hat{G}_{C'}$ are equivalent as central extensions. The same holds for $H^2 (\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{R})$ for a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.

(c) If $T:G\to U(PH)$ is a unitary projective representation of $G$ (with 2-cocycle $C$ as a phase), then there exists unitary representation  $\hat{T}:\hat{G}_C \to U(H)$ such that $T\pi =\gamma \hat{T}$ in which $\pi :\hat{G}_C \to G$ and $\gamma :U(H)\to U(PH)$.

(d) By Bargmann’s theorem, if $H^2 (\tilde{\mathfrak{g}};\mathbb{R})=0$ (where $\tilde{\mathfrak{g}}$ is the Lie algebra of $\tilde{G}$), then there is one-to-one correspondence between unitary representations of $\tilde{G}$ and unitary projective representations of $G$.

**My questions**:

(i) What does the author mean by the most general central extension $\hat{\tilde{G}}$ of $\tilde{G}$? And how we can do steps (2) and (3)?

(ii) If $C$ is a real 2-cocycle on $G$, can we build a unitary representation $T:G\to U(PH)$? (I mean does the converse of (a) hold?)

(iii) If $H^2 (\tilde{\mathfrak{g}};\mathbb{R})=\neq 0$ in (d), what can we do?

Comment: *What does the author mean by the most general central extension?* Do you understand central extensions but don’t understand what “the most general one” means? Or do you not understand what a central extension is?

Comment: Yes, I know the definiton of central extensions well. But I don't understand what the most general one is.